# Rails 3 Make Text into a Clickable Link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've made a Rails 3 app and I've got a form on my page in which I have users copy and paste a link and then submit it (much like Reddit) and then ideally, the link would appear on the main page for other users to click on.  However, whenever users paste the URL's into my form, the link is not clickable, it is only text. Does anyone know any solutions for this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: Huh? Do you mean auto-link without them submitting anything?

Comment: I meant that currently, when users submit a URL, the URL will display as text (and therefore unclickable).  If someone wanted to click on it to take them to the new page, they wouldn't be able to do so.  I'd like the URL to actually take the user to the webpage.  Does this make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So say your object is in `@post`

In the display, do `<%= link_to @post.url, @post.url %>`

That should "linkify" your URL so that users can click it.

Comment: I tried that, but I keep getting an undefined method 'url' error.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Well, replace `.url` with whatever the attribute is named that you are storing your URL in.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!  Worked perfectly.